# Update statement not filtering on conditions, defaulting to "else" using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My update statement should be hitting the second line in the case statement. However, it is defaulting to the Else line. Is there a syntax problem with this line?

I have ran the select statement using the same conditions and it is returning this record.

```
SELECT issues.issue_type, issues.priority, issues.credentials, issues.status_id
FROM engagements 
LEFT OUTER JOIN issues ON issues.application_id = engagements.application_id 
WHERE 
    engagements.id = 5699 AND 
    issues.status_id <> 4 AND 
    issues.credentials = 1 AND 
    issues.issue_type IN ('EAPT', 'ENPT') AND 
    issues.priority = 'Medium';


Issue Type | priority | credentials | status.id
EAPT       |  Medium  |  1          |    1
```

The update statement I am running is below. From the record above, I believe it should be catching on the second case line, but it is not.

```
UPDATE engagements
LEFT OUTER JOIN issues ON issues.application_id = 
engagements.application_id
SET engagements.engagement_score_ewc_id = 
     (CASE 
        WHEN (issues.credentials = 1 AND issues.issue_type IN ('EAPT', 'ENPT') AND issues.priority IN ('High', 'Critical') AND issues.status_id <> 4) THEN 3
        WHEN (issues.credentials = 1 AND issues.issue_type IN ('EAPT', 'ENPT') AND issues.priority IN ('Medium') AND issues.status_id <> 4) THEN 2
        WHEN (issues.credentials = 1 AND issues.issue_type IN ('EAPT', 'ENPT') AND issues.priority IN ('Low') AND issues.status_id <> 4) THEN 1
        ELSE 3
      END)
WHERE engagements.id = 5699;
```

Comment: You aren't showing issues status..

Comment: is application_id unique on the issues table...guessing you might have joins with multiple records possibly...if so...the filter needs to be on the join...not on the set statement

Comment: Updated select statement per P.Salmon. 

Application_id is unique as it is a foreign key.

Comment: Something doesn;t look right you are joining on engagements.application_id but testing engagements.id ?

Comment: So an application can have multiple engagements and issues. But engagements and issues can only have one application. At the end is why I am setting the where clause to a specific engagement.

Comment: You are updating on engagement record for multiple issues records - so the outcome will be whatever last record the update finds in issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE engagements
LEFT OUTER JOIN issues ON issues.application_id = 
engagements.application_id
SET engagements.engagement_score_ewc_id = 
     (CASE 
        WHEN issues.priority IN ('High', 'Critical') THEN 3
        WHEN issues.priority IN ('Medium') THEN 2
        WHEN issues.priority IN ('Low') THEN 1
        ELSE 3
      END)
WHERE engagements.id = 5699
and issues.credentials = 1
and issues.issue_type IN ('EAPT', 'ENPT')
and issues.status_id<>4
```

Why can't we use all the common conditions in the where clause instead of in the Case statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should run *this* query:

```
SELECT i.issue_type, i.priority, i.credentials, i.status_id
FROM engagements e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     issues i
     ON i.application_id = e.application_id 
WHERE e.id = 5699;
```

My guess is that you will have multiple rows.

That means that your `update` is updating the same row multiple times -- and which one gets the final value is indeterminate.

One method is to repeat the same `where` conditions in the `update` query.  You might have other solutions as well -- say selecting one particular record from the second table.